# Can't access Julia Array ( BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Vector{Int64} at index [1] )

Tags: arrays, julia

Julia Code:

```
seed = 1234
N = 2
newNum = Int64[]
for i in 1:N
    seq = digits(seed*seed, pad=8)
    seed = seq[6]*1000+seq[5]*100+seq[4]*10+seq[3]
    newNum[i] = seed
end
newNum[2]
```

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p390.png

Comment: You have to `push!` the elements, or better yet, create the vector with a comprehension or `map`.

Comment: Tried to add them with push but din't worked well - can you show me what you mean in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
seed = 1234
N = 2
newNum = Int64[]
for i in 1:N
    seq = digits(seed*seed, pad=8)
    seed = seq[6]*1000+seq[5]*100+seq[4]*10+seq[3]
    push!(newNum, seed)
end
newNum[2]
```

or

```
seed = 1234
N = 2
newNum = Vector{Int64}(undef, N)
for i in 1:N
    seq = digits(seed*seed, pad=8)
    seed = seq[6]*1000+seq[5]*100+seq[4]*10+seq[3]
    newNum[i] = seed
end
newNum[2]
```

However, in general, I would recommend you to wrap this code in a function, as otherwise it will be inefficient, and moreover if you try running it as a script (i.e. not interactively in REPL) you will get an error:

```
┌ Warning: Assignment to `seed` in soft scope is ambiguous because a global variable by the same name exists: `seed` will 
be treated as a new local. Disambiguate by using `local seed` to suppress this warning or `global seed` to assign to the existing global variable.
└ 
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: seed not defined
```

The reason is that `seed` is a global variable that you rebind in local scope introduced by `for` loop. You might want to check out [this part](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#On-Soft-Scope) of the Julia Manual to learn more about it.

Comment: Thanks. I got it on my own using a vector instead of an array as you did as well. The code is part of a function, just for keeping it simple it only took that snipet that is sufficient to understand the problem. Thanks for posting a solution!